# Finding All Palindrome Numbers Within A Range Using The Number Of Digits Of The Numbers

Tags: loops, palindrome

so I have to write a program that will find all the palindrome numbers within a range using a numDigits method that takes an int number and returns the number of digits of that number and a isPalindrome method that takes an int number and returns a boolean true or false. This is in java.

I have a numDigits method coded and working well but i dont know how to take the output of that and use it to find all the palindromes within a range

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Digits
{

  public static void main(String [] args) 
  {
    //variables 
    int number = 0, numDigits; 
    final int END = 10000; 

    //calculations
    numDigits = getNumDigits(number, END); 

}// end of Main method 
public static int getNumDigits(int number, int END) 
{  
    //local variables 
    int numDigits;

      numDigits = 0;

        while(number <= END)
        { 

         numDigits = (int)(Math.log10(number)+1);

            if(number == 0) 
            { 
                numDigits = 1;
            }

                isPalindrome(number, numDigits);

                  number++;

      }//end of loop

      return numDigits;
}// numDigit Method
public static boolean isPalindrome(int number, int numDigits)
{
    //local variables 
    boolean palindrome;

    while(numDigits == 1)
    {
        palindrome = true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste what you have coded so far ?

Comment: What is the getNumDigits supposed to do exactly?  Is it meant to return the number of digits per number?

Comment: yes it returns the number of digits in a number

Comment: I am not sure exactly what is the link between your getNumDigits function and isPalindrome function, but I would see it like this: in your loop from 0 to 10000, check if isPalindrome(n) then return n ?

Comment: what exactly does n represent there?

Comment: It would be your current number in the while loop

Comment: my program has to print all palindromes between 0 and 10000 but the methods have to be general and have to work with all int numbers.

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer with an additional `if (isPalindrome(number, numDigits)) { System.out.print(number); }`, also the end of the isPalindrome function was missing so I assumed you already had it

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it (though I'm not a java programmer so there might be some syntax errors).

```
public class Digits
{

  public static void main(String [] args) 
  {
    //variables 
    int number = 0, numDigits; 
    final int END = 10000; 

    //calculations
    numDigits = getNumDigits(number, END); 

}// end of Main method 

public static int getNumDigits(int number, int END) 
{  
    //local variables 
    int numDigits;
    numDigits = 0;
    while(number <= END)
    { 
        numDigits = (int)(Math.log10(number)+1);

        if(number == 0) 
        { 
            numDigits = 1;
        }

        if (isPalindrome(number, numDigits)) {
            System.out.print(number);
        }

        number++;

      }//end of loop

      return numDigits;
}// numDigit Method

public static boolean isPalindrome(int number, int numDigits)
{
    //local variables 
    boolean palindrome;

    while(numDigits == 1)
    {
        palindrome = true;
    }

    // missing end of function
}
```